# Issue to display scene

Tags: javafx

I have an issue while working with javafx. I want to display a single stage with a scene containing a panel (main panel with menus) containing itself a panel (information).

My issue is as follows : either I see a double panel content in the window (as shown in below picture) or an empty panel depending on the order of actions between set scene, set center panel, show window. Bug display:
[image]

Here is what I want to see :

[image: UI that I want]

The code I am using :

```
package org.HangmanGameFXViews;

import java.io.IOException;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage stagePrincipal;

    public Stage getStagePrincipal() {
        return stagePrincipal;
    }


    private BorderPane mainPane;
    private AnchorPane homePane;
    private AnchorPane rulesPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        stagePrincipal = primaryStage;
        stagePrincipal.setTitle("Application de gestion de personnes");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/MainContainer.fxml"));
        try {
            mainPane = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader();
        loader2.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/Home.fxml"));
        try {
            homePane = loader2.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mainPane.setCenter(homePane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        stagePrincipal.setScene(scene);
        stagePrincipal.show();



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The Home.fxml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="473.0" prefWidth="378.0" stylesheets="@textarea.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="368.0" text="Bienvenue dans le jeu du PENDU" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fitHeight="291.0" fitWidth="539.0" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../resources/pictures/homePicture.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <TextArea editable="false" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="318.0" prefHeight="147.0" prefWidth="368.0" text="Vous avez 7 coups pour trouver le mot cacher et si vous réussissez... et bien on recommence!&#10;&#10;Plus vous avez trouvez de mots, plus votre score grandira!! Alors à vous de jouer!&#10;PROVERBE : &quot;Pas vu, pas pris!&#10;                     Pris! PENDU!!!&quot;" wrapText="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The MainContainers.fxml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.HangmanGameFXViews.view.MenuesActions">
   <top>
      <MenuBar maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="400.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Fichiers">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Nouveau" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToRules" text="Règles" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quitter" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="À propos" />
         </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

The Rules.fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="413.0" prefWidth="459.0" stylesheets="@textarea.css" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1">
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="459.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="3.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Le jeu du PENDU" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Black" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextArea editable="false" layoutY="25.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="76.0" prefWidth="459.0" text="Vous avez 7 coups pour trouver le mot caché ! Et si vous réussissez : on recommence !&#10;Plus vous acez trouvé de mots, plus votre score grandira !! Alors à vous de jouer !" wrapText="true" />
            <TextArea editable="false" layoutY="118.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="179.0" prefWidth="459.0" text="COMPTES DES POINTS :&#10;                        &#10;                           Mot trouve sans erreur...............................100Pts&#10;                           Mot trouve avec 1 erreur.............................50Pts&#10;                           Mot trouve avec 2 erreurs...........................35Pts&#10;                           Mot trouve avec 3 erreurs...........................25Pts&#10;                           Mot trouve avec 4 erreurs............................15Pts&#10;                           Mot trouve avec 5 erreurs............................10Pts&#10;                           Mot trouve avec 6 erreurs............................5Pts" wrapText="true">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </TextArea>
            <TextArea editable="false" layoutY="296.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="117.0" prefWidth="459.0" text="Je vous souhaite bien du plaisir ....&#10;Et si vous pensez pouvoir trouver un mot en un coup, c'est que vous pensez que le dictionnaire est petit !&#10;Hors, pour votre information il comprend plus de 330 000 mots ... donc bonne chance." wrapText="true" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
```

Thank you for any helps.

Comment: Please post [mre]. An image of how you want the gui to look like could also help.

Comment: I have done the edit hoping it is enough. The java code is a class that work alone with the fxml files.

Comment: It is better but needs more work. The problem should be **r**eproducible and complete. Meaning we should be able to copy-paste and run it.  (`MenuesActions` is missing for example) 
The code should demonstrate the problem, and nothing else (**m**) so you need to remove everything which is not essential to demonstrate it. Remove dependencies of unavailable resources (like images). If needed use web images. (`Rules.fxml` is incomplete)

Comment: Ok I understand better now. I will clean and update thank you.

Comment: I edit the question to have less code.

Comment: The code posted is indded more of an MRE. To  make it **M** you could remove `Rules.fxml` which is not used and `AnchorPane rulesPane`. To make it **R** you  need to remove `onAction` and `fx:controller` from `MainContainers.fxml` and `<Image url="@../../../../resources/pictures/homePicture.jpg" />` from `Home.fxml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an MRE for the required layout can be demonstrated with the following 3 files:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        BorderPane mainPane = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("MainContainer.fxml"));
        AnchorPane homePane =  FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("Home.fxml"));
        mainPane.setCenter(homePane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MainContainer.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="500.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <MenuBar maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"  prefWidth="400.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
      <!--THIS WAS THE REASON FOR THE WRONG LAYOUT prefHeight="500.0" --> 
         <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Fichiers">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Nouveau" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quitter" />
               </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="À propos" />
         </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Home.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="473.0" prefWidth="378.0" stylesheets="@textarea.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="368.0" 
      text="Bienvenue dans le jeu du PENDU" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fitHeight="291.0" fitWidth="539.0" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">

      </ImageView>
      <TextArea editable="false" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="318.0" prefHeight="147.0" prefWidth="368.0" 
      text="Vous avez 7 coups pour trouver le mot cacher et si vous réussissez... et bien on recommence!&#10;&#10;Plus vous avez trouvez de mots, plus votre score grandira!! Alors à vous de jouer!&#10;PROVERBE : &quot;Pas vu, pas pris!&#10;                     Pris! PENDU!!!&quot;" wrapText="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I am glad I could help.